# Power Series: Can anyone recommend a book?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This isn't a specific mathematics question, but I am just wondering if anyone can recommend a good book for studying power series? Possibly part of a calculus or analysis text?

Thanks
C.

Comment: I recommend Thomas calculus, J.Stewart calculus. But you can find a lot of documents and also videos on the internet.

Answer (score 6):

Certainly, you can find good notes on the web, but you might also want to peruse these books:

- Infinite Sequences and Series, Knopp
- Theory and Application of Infinite Series, Knopp
- Calculus books like Spivak
- Analysis books like Rudin (Principles of mathematical Analysis, short section)

Here are some web resources:

- [*Book Boon*](http://bookboon.com/en/calculus-3b-ebook#download)
- [*Power Series*](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Power_series) (Also note the other related books at the bottom of the page.)
- [*Notes on PS*](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/243series7.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20130728124334/http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/243series7.pdf), later version of notes on [Honors Calculus](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/2400full.pdf))
- [*Powers Series and Convergence Issues*](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Evipul/teaching-1011/153/powerseries.pdf)
- [*Lecture notes on several complex
  variables*](http://www.math.tamu.edu/%7Eboas/courses/650-2011c/notes.pdf)
- [*Math Open Reference*](http://www.mathopenref.com/calcpowerseries.html)
- [*Paul's Online Notes*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PowerSeries.aspx)

Comment: This helpful post needs a TU! +1